# how to manipulate ul brackets

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

hy all, I am creating an accordion menu that when i press the " UNIT " tab, it opens up a list of " Chapters " tab, and when i press on any one of those chapters, a list of lessons opens up. Till now, i have managed to create all the appropriate lists, but in default, lessons and chapters are opened automatically, and the lessons elements when pressed do not scroll back up to the chapters parents. My html5 file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqueryjs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqueryuiaccor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#accordion').accordion();
    });
</script>

<div id="container">
<div id="content">
<div id="sidebar">
        <ul id="accordion">
            <li>
                <a href="#recent" class="heading">Unit 1</a>    
                    <ul id="accordion">             
                        <li> <a href="#recent" class="heading">Chapter 1 </a> </li>
                                <ul id="accordion2">
                                    <li> Lesson 1 </li>
                                </ul>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <a href="#recent" class="heading">Unit 2</a>    

                    <ul id="accordion">             
                        <li> <a href="#recent" class="heading">Chapter 1 </a> </li>
                                <ul id="accordion">
                                    <li> <a href="#recent" class="heading" role="tab" aria-expanded="true">Chapter 2 </a>
                                        <ul id="accordion">
                                            <li> <a href="#recent" class="heading">Lesson 1 </a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                    </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>       
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My acorjs.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul#accordion a.heading').click(function() {
        $(this).css('outline','none');
        if($(this).parent().hasClass('current')) {
            $(this).siblings('ul').slideUp('slow',function() {
                $(this).parent().removeClass('current');
                $.scrollTo('#accordion',1000);

            });
        } else {
            $('ul#accordion li.current ul').slideUp('slow',function() {
                $(this).parent().removeClass('current');
            });
            $(this).siblings('ul').slideToggle('slow',function() {
                $(this).parent().toggleClass('current');
            });
            $.scrollTo('#accordion',1000);

        }
        return false;

    });

});
```

Any ideas??

My new edited file :

```
<div id="container">
<div id="content">
<div id="sidebar">

        <ul class="accordion">
    <li>
      <a href="#recent" class="heading">Unit 1</a>    
        <ul class="accordion">             
            <li> <a href="#recent" class="heading">Chapter 1 </a> </li>
                <ul id="accordion2">
                    <li> Lesson 1 </li>
                </ul>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#recent" class="heading">Unit 2</a>    
        <ul class="accordion">             
            <li> <a href="#recent" class="heading">Chapter 1 </a> </li>
                <ul id="accordion2">
                    <li> Lesson 1 </li>
                </ul>
        </ul>
    </li>



        </ul>       
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my JS file :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.accordion a.heading').click(function() {
        $(this).css('outline','none');
        if($(this).parent().hasClass('current')) {
            $(this).siblings('ul').slideUp('slow',function() {
                $(this).parent().removeClass('current');
                $.scrollTo('#accordion',1000);
            });
        } else {
            $('ul.accordion li.current ul').slideUp('slow',function() {
                $(this).parent().removeClass('current');
            });
            $(this).siblings('ul').slideToggle('slow',function() {
                $(this).parent().toggleClass('current');
            });
            $.scrollTo('#accordion',1000);

        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Please help everything stopped working

Comment: Element IDs should be unique. Accessing elements by ID will only ever return one element or null if there are no matches. If there are multiple elements with the same ID, behaviour is unspecified—usually the first is returned but there is no guarantee of that.

Answer (score 2):

Try giving the `ul` elements unique ids. The ul for both Units and Chapters have "accordion" as the id. If the ids are not unique, the event function may be bound only to the first or last, but not all

Alternately, make "accordion" a class and not an id. Your jquery will then need to change to use "ul.accordion" instead of "ul#accordion".

Here's a snippet of the HTML showing the change:

```
<ul class="accordion">
  <li>
      <a href="#recent" class="heading">Unit 1</a>    
      <ul class="accordion">             
        <li> <a href="#recent" class="heading">Chapter 1 </a> </li>
        <ul id="accordion2">
          <li> Lesson 1 </li>
```

And then the change to the javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.accordion a.heading').click(function() {
        $(this).css('outline','none');
        if($(this).parent().hasClass('current')) {
            $(this).siblings('ul').slideUp('slow',function() {
                $(this).parent().removeClass('current');
                $.scrollTo('#accordion',1000);
            });
        } else {
            $('ul.accordion li.current ul').slideUp('slow',function() {
                $(this).parent().removeClass('current');
            });
            $(this).siblings('ul').slideToggle('slow',function() {
                $(this).parent().toggleClass('current');
            });
            $.scrollTo('#accordion',1000);

        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I thank you for your answer, but i am really new At this and i am working myself up using tutorials and stuff. Could you please show me how to this. I thank you in advance

Comment: I changed it but nothing worked at all:S please see my edited question and help me out:S

Comment: I don't see any edits from  you on the question yet. It would really help if you could be clearer about the specific problem(s) you're trying to solve. Your question is a bit vague.

Comment: The edit should appear now, i want when i press the chapters, the lessons will scroll down from it. if u need any more files please tell me and i really appreciate the help